# get sql query result in xml format?

Tags: sql-server

Hello i am trying the getting result in xml format in the sql server but i don't get propare xml format many data it's repeat in xml format. i have write this query in the sql server but not a getting propare data. any one know where is my mistake then please let me know how can do that.

Here i have write this query :

```
select * from (

    SELECT SSCF.SubSubCategoryId AS InterestId,c.FeedId,c.Description,u.UserId,u.Email,u.UserName,u.ProfileImage,u.Name,
           ISNULL(SSCL.SubSubCategory,SSC.SubSubCategory) AS Interest,
           1 AS [Type]
    FROM SubSubCategoryFollowers SSCF
    LEFT JOIN SubSubCategories SSC ON SSCF.SubSubCategoryId = SSC.SubSubCategoryId              
    INNER JOIN Feed c on c.FeedId = SSC.FeedId
    inner join Users u on u.UserId = SSCF.UserId
    WHERE u.Email is not null

    UNION ALL

    SELECT  SCF.SubCategoryId AS InterestId,c.FeedId,c.Description,u.UserId,u.Email,u.UserName,u.ProfileImage,u.Name,
           ISNULL(SCL.SubCategory,SC.SubCategory) AS Interest,
           2 AS [Type]
    FROM SubCategoryFollowers SCF
    LEFT JOIN SubCategories SC ON SCF.SubCategoryId = SC.SubCategoryId              
    INNER JOIN Feed c on c.FeedId = SC.FeedId
    inner join Users u on u.UserId = SCF.UserId
    WHERE u.Email is not null 

 )as res 

group by res.UserId,res.InterestId,res.FeedId,res.Description,res.Email,res.Interest,res.Type,res.UserName,res.ProfileImage,res.Name
order by res.FeedId             
OFFSET 1   ROWS
FETCH NEXT  50000   ROWS ONLY
FOR XML PATH('User'), ROOT ('Users')
```

this is my current op =>

```
 <Users>
  <User>
    <UserId>1660</UserId>
    <Email>xyz.com</Email>
    <UserName>xyz</UserName>
    <ProfileImage>20160717035320958.jpeg</ProfileImage>     
    <InterestId>15</InterestId>
    <FeedId>4689</FeedId>
    <Description>Test</Description>         
    <Interest>Event</Interest>
    <Type>2</Type>
</User>
<User>  
     <UserId>1660</UserId>
    <Email>xyz.com</Email>
    <UserName>xyz</UserName>
    <ProfileImage>20160717035320958.jpeg</ProfileImage> 
    <InterestId>16</InterestId>
    <FeedId>4689</FeedId>
    <Description>Test</Description>        
    <Interest>Party</Interest>
    <Type>2</Type>
</User>
<User>
    <UserId>1660</UserId>
    <Email>xyz.com</Email>
    <UserName>xyz</UserName>
    <ProfileImage>20160717035320958.jpeg</ProfileImage> 
    <InterestId>21</InterestId>
    <FeedId>4689</FeedId>
    <Description>Test</Description>      
    <Interest>Club</Interest>
    <Type>2</Type>
</User>
<User>
<UserId>1661</UserId>
<Email>abc.com</Email>
<UserName>abc</UserName>
<ProfileImage>20160717035320959.jpeg</ProfileImage>     
<InterestId>15</InterestId>
<FeedId>4690</FeedId>
<Description>Test1</Description>         
<Interest>Cricket</Interest>
<Type>1</Type>
```

My expected o/p =>

```
<Users>
 <User>
 <UserId>1660</UserId>
<Email>xyz.com</Email>
<UserName>xyz</UserName>
 <ProfileImage>20160717035320958.jpeg</ProfileImage>  

<InterestId>15</InterestId>
<FeedId>4689</FeedId>
<Description>Test</Description>         
<Interest>Event</Interest>
<Type>2</Type>

<InterestId>16</InterestId>
<FeedId>4689</FeedId>
<Description>Test</Description>        
<Interest>Party</Interest>
<Type>2</Type>

<InterestId>21</InterestId>
<FeedId>4689</FeedId>
<Description>Test</Description>      
<Interest>Club</Interest>
<Type>2</Type>
</User>
<User>
<UserId>1661</UserId>
<Email>abc.com</Email>
<UserName>abc</UserName>
<ProfileImage>20160717035320959.jpeg</ProfileImage>  

<InterestId>15</InterestId>
<FeedId>4690</FeedId>
<Description>Test1</Description>         
<Interest>Cricket</Interest>
<Type>1</Type>
```

i want like this data in xml format any one know please let me know.

Comment: What is the result of your query as is and how is it different to your desired output?

Comment: right now in i have repeat this data as well like UserId is repeat all the data is repeat so i need the stop this repeat data

Comment: @iamdave can i post my current op so you can easy to understand?

Comment: Yes, please add your current output to your question.

Comment: @iamdave i have edit my question you can check this and please help me on that.

Comment: As far as I am aware that is how XML works?  Is your current output giving you any actual problems with wherever you are using the generated XML?

Comment: @iamdave so can you please let me know where is my mistake in the query?

Comment: Why do you think there is a mistake?  Is your XML file not working when uploaded/processed in another application?

Comment: try SSCF.SubSubCategoryId AS InterestId AS "User/InterestId"

Comment: @Jayvee can you please give me the new post as a answer so i can easy to understand

Comment: @coderwill will do in a few minutes.

Comment: guys any one know how can do that this task

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have an example for your case.
You could use `TYPE` to get nested xml

```
DECLARE @SampleData AS TABLE
(
    UserId INT,
    Email varchar(200),
    UserName varchar(200),
    InterestId int,
    Description varchar(200)
)

INSERT INTO @SampleData
(
    UserId,
    Email,
    UserName,
    InterestId,
    Description
)
VALUES
(1,'1@abc.xyz','User1', 100, 'Description 100'),
(1,'1@abc.xyz','User1', 101, 'Description 101'),
(1,'1@abc.xyz','User1', 102, 'Description 102'),
(1,'1@abc.xyz','User1', 103, 'Description 103')


SELECT  sd.UserId,
       sd.Email,
       sd.UserName,
       (
          SELECT sd2.InterestId,
                sd2.Description 
          FROM @SampleData sd2
          WHERE sd2.UserId = sd.UserId
          FOR XML PATH (''), TYPE
       ) 
FROM 
(   select DISTINCT sd.UserId, sd.Email, sd.UserName
    FROM @SampleData sd
) sd
FOR XML PATH('User') ,ROOT('Users')
```

Returns

```
<Users>
  <User>
    <UserId>1</UserId>
    <Email>1@abc.xyz</Email>
    <UserName>User1</UserName>
    <InterestId>100</InterestId>
    <Description>Description 100</Description>
    <InterestId>101</InterestId>
    <Description>Description 101</Description>
    <InterestId>102</InterestId>
    <Description>Description 102</Description>
    <InterestId>103</InterestId>
    <Description>Description 103</Description>
  </User>
</Users>
```

Demo link: http://rextester.com/KKEHCR86171

Comment: Triv with my query how can do that in query i can used union also so

Comment: can you please give me with my query your answer so it's very use full for me this solution it's also 100% good but i can't modify with my query so please can you more one help

Comment: You should try yourself. I think it's not so hard to map my answer with your code.... :)

Comment: i am getting this error  The FOR XML clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables, and subqueries when they contain a set operator. To work around, wrap the SELECT containing a set operator using derived table syntax and apply FOR XML on top of it.

Comment: Hello triv i am trying to add your solution with my query and i am get result also but pagination is not working so any idea?

Answer (score 2):

The idea is to give the xml the format you want by labelling the path tags.
Unfortunately I don't have time to work through your sqls but this is an example of grouping by labelling:

```
select UserId as "User" , InterestId as "User/InterestId" from
(select '1' as 'UserId', 'I1' as 'InterestId'
union all 
select '1' as 'UserId', 'I2' as 'InterestId') x
for xml path(''), root('Users')
```